# Переписать небольшую функцию на C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, webgl

Очень прошу помощи.
В общем создаю проект WebGl. Все прекрасно работает в самой unity, но когда делаю билд под WebGL, то одна функция не отрабатывает, из-за чего вся игра ложится.
Прошу помочь переписать функцию ниже, ибо я не разбираюсь в асинхронных функциях(изначально, этот фрагмент кода делал другой человек, с которым связи уже нет)
Желательно, чтобы использовался IEnumerator, но любая реализация подойдет, лишь бы работало уже

Итак, злополучная функция:

```
private async void StartGame()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            OnTurn = Players[(int)Board.OnTurn];
            if (NoPossibleMoves()) break;

            Move move = await OnTurn.CalculateNextMove();

            if (OnTurn is Bot)
            {
                Bot bot = OnTurn as Bot;
                UiController.ShowSearchInfoText(bot.LastSearchResult);
                SelectPiece((int)move.FromSq);
                DoMove((int)move.ToSq);
            }
            else
            {
                await OnTurn.SelectPiece();
                if (SelectedPiece == null) continue;
                await OnTurn.DoMove();
            }
        }
        EndGame();
    }
```

Спасибо всем неравнодушным!

Comment: [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async)

Comment: Во-первых, с переписыванием кода Вы ошиблись сайтом. Во-вторых, закройте свои предыдущие вопросы, выбрав ответы (или укажите, что ответы не решают Вашей проблемы).

Comment: "функция не отрабатывает" что означает - функция совсем не запускается? или падает с ошибкой? в отладчике пробовали смотреть что происходит?

Comment: @CrazyElf ошибок в отладчике нет, функция запускается, но почему то не работает, сам ломаю голову

Comment: Добавьте логирование, отлаживайте.

Comment: @МихаилЧеремисин Ну что значит "не работает"? Во-первых - как именно она запускается, unity3d её автоматом запускает или вы её как-то запускаете? Во-вторых если туда попадает управление, то можете посмотреть в отладчике, что дальше происходит, хотя в асинхронном коде это не всегда бывает легко.

Comment: С async/await есть такая штука, что использовав в одном месте они начинают распростряняться по всему коду. Вы наивно полагаете, что ограничитесь одной функцией.  Нет, не выйдет - это затронет автоматически и другие места кода. Так что если вы захотите убрать async - придётся убирать везде. Либо разбираться в том, как это работает - потому что очень плохо работать с кодом, не понимая как он устроен и как работает. Это как писать юридические документы на чужом языке и не разбираясь в юриспруденции. Выбор за вами и сделать его можете только вы, ведь вы даже не объяснили что не так с кодом.